# What is a bootstrap widget?

Tags: widgets, bootstrap

I am using (customizing) a Bootstrap 4 template and have come across several "widgets" mentioned in the HTML code (e.g., `single-sidebar-widget`, `editors-pick-widget`). However, I can't see that they do anything. I understand there are certain widgets that do things (e.g., tooltips) and they have code but many, like the two mentioned above, don't seem to have any code.

I may be off-base here with the topic of this post, if I am let me know and I will remove it. However, I have tried to find a decent explanation but can't find any. If there is, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap doesnt contain any "widget" code in its source. The "single-sidebar-widget" and "editors-pick-widget" may just be additions included in the specific template you are working with. Typically these can be standalone blocks of code that can be placed wherever you like.